# Joomla 3 Template override a plugin

Tags: templates, plugins, joomla

I could not find any info on overriding a Joomla plugin in my template.
Some forums claimed there was no plugin override, and the Joomla documentation (being the menacing forest that it is) either has nothing on the subject, or the page is hard to find.

So how can we override the output of a Joomla plugin in the same was we override the output of com_content or mod_contact?

Comment: Love this question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found a way to do this:

1. Navigate to `<joomla_homefolder>/administrator/language/<your_language>/`
2. Search for the plugin's corresponding language file.
3. Copy the file name, EXCLUDING the language prefix (ie `en-GB.`) and the `.ini` suffix.
4. In your template create a folder named `html` (a common practice for template overrides).
5. In the `html` folder create a subfolder and name with the language file name as you copied it in step 3.
6. Navigate to the `tmpl` subfolder in the plugin's path: `<joomla_homefolder>/plugins/<plugin_type>/<plugin_name>/tmpl`
7. Copy the view file you wish to override into the folder you've created in step 5.
8. Modify the copied file to override the plugins output.

For example -
To change the page navigation buttons - modify the output of `<joomla_homefolder>/plugins/content/pagenavigation`:

Go into `<joomla_homefolder>/administrator/language/en-GB/` and find the file named `en-GB.plg_content_pagenavigation.ini`.

From the filename copy only `plg_content_pagenavigation`.

Create a folder named `html` (If it does not exist already) in your theme, inside it create a subfolder and name it `plg_content_pagenavigation`.

Copy the view file `<joomla_homefolder>/plugins/content/pagenavigation/tmpl/default.php` into the `plg_content_pagenavigation` folder you just created.

Modify the file.

Note: I have tried it only with Joomla 3.1.
The method may not work with some plugins.

Good Luck.

Comment: To create a language override you can do this via the backend, which may be less confusing.  https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Language_Overrides_in_Joomla the other advice is really useful and can't be done via the backend override.  I will test this, could be really useful.

Answer (score 6):

In joomla 3 you can override plugins output only, that's why the origin plugin must be implemented with a tmpl.
The naming convention  of the folder in you [template]/html is

> plg_[**type***]_[pluginElement]

Template overridden native joomla plugins is only the pagenavigation.

**type*** : obviously there's no sense to be other than content but if it's custom plugin no one can stop you.

Comment: By the way, this totally works with the new Custom Fields in Joomla 3.7. Meaning you can use this folder name convention and stick the template file from a field in it and mod the file to override the field output. For example in the html folder you put plg_fields_media with the media.php file inside it to override the media field.

Comment: @BrianPeat that is awesome!

Answer (score 2):

On a Joomla 3.1 install, I am using the Simple Image Gallery plugin and I felt the need to override it in order to add extra functionality to each thumbnail of the gallery.

I copied all of the contents of `<joomla_homefolder>/plugins/content/jw_sig/jw_sig/tmpl/` into the folder `<joomla_homefolder>/templates/protostar/html/jw_sig/` and I was then able to modify both the `default.php` file for output modifications, and the accompanying `template.css` file for styling modifications.  This successfully overrides the plugin's output without risking issues during future updates.

Of course, this will not work with all plugins, but it offers another alternative if you have a plugin that was nice enough to be developed with a `tmpl` folder.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't override the same way because there is not tmpl folder because plugins really should not be rendering though of course a lot do.  You probably need to clone the plugin and make a the layout your want possibly using a jlayout to make it easier to manage.

Comment: Good idea.  Although the other answer suggests a /tmpl folder may not be strictly necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Elin's answer is not quite correct for Joomla 2.5-3.x. Some plugins do render screen output and have /tmpl folders that you may be able to override. See http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla

In some cases you may need to create alternative views within the plugin /tmpl folder. For example, some of the simple, newer custom content components that use JForms let you add fields to com_content articles and select a view template for each field. Then overrides for com_content are generated dynamically to display the custom fields. Each field type can be displayed in the component area through plugins, or in a module, or within the template code, but it will use the /tmpl file you selected for the field in the CCK component. If there is a way to override the different field views from within the template folder, it must require an arcane menu structure I haven't been able to discover.

Comment: I specifically said they "shouldn't" not that they "don't."   However the use of JLayouts is structurally more correct.

Comment: I was mainly responding to your "can't." :-)

Comment: Also the jw_sig answer seems to indicate you may be able to override other php files too.